# Unbinded function was calling in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a function named "onchange". On button click I trigger the change event of the textbox. I haven't bound an event to the textbox.

But when manually trigger the change event for the textbox, the `onchange()` function is called and shows the alert message

```js
    
   
 $('#btn').on('click',function(){
    $('.numeric').trigger('change')
 })
 function onchange(){
    alert("hi")
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Name: <input type="text" class="numeric" name="user"></p>
    <input type="button" id="btn" value="click"/>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) It's not at all clear what you're asking above, can you edit your question to clarify?

Comment: Congratulations! And what is your question? What is your issue? What is the expected result, etc.......

Comment: You need to attach your `onchange` function to the `.numeric' element

Comment: Why would you trigger an onchange event? I don't see the use of it. Onchange is an event triggered if the input is changed, but it doesn't change anything in this example.

Comment: May it helps [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pandeyvishal1986/jjmntyyf/#&togetherjs=ksIIV3tMvL)

Answer (score 0):

could be what you want?

```js
          

$(".numeric").on('change',function(){
  alert("hi")
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Name: <input type="text" class="numeric" name="user"></p>
```